# Trying to make a footer sitemap with css (the footer is made out of ul li)

Tags: css, html-lists, footer, sitemap

I want it to look similar to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eO1dZ.gif

I've been trying out a few different things but nothing seems to make it neat horizontal list like the picture. Can someone help me out?

```
  <!-- Footer informatie -->
    <footer>
        <section id="sitemap">
            <h2>Sitemap</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Opleiding</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Visie &amp; Beleid</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Opbouw Studieprogramma</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Competenties</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Diploma</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Beroepen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Onderwijsprogramma</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Mededelingen</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Uitagenda</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Propedeuse</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Verdieping 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Verdieping 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Afstuderen</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Organisatie</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Docenten</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Onderwijsbureau</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Stagebureau</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Buitenlandbureau</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Examencommissie</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Decaan</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Stages en Projecten</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Stages</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projecten</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </section>
```

and my css so far:

```
#sitemap li {
list-style-type:none; 
display: inline-block;
border: 2px solid;
}
```

The inline block should make it horizonal but it doesnt... What am i doing wrong?

x

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/n08r24rm/ This is what your code looks like.

Answer (score 0):

By using `#sitemap li` you target EVERY li inside the #sitemap element, while in fact you only want to target the containing li's.

You might want to use this instead:

```
#sitemap > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
    border: 2px solid;
}
```